# Ways to find one number in a pair given another number and their greatest common di

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I would like to know if there is a way to find number in a pair of number given another number and their greatest common divisor.

Example: find all n values given n <= 50 and gcd(n,50) =5.

Comment: Hint: count the odd multiples of $5$ which are not a multiple of $25$.

Comment: You mean a closed formula? or an algorithm?

Comment: Any way is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, we can find $n$ values by first factoring the given integer ($50$ in this case) as 
$$50 = 2\cdot 5^2$$
Then, $n$ must have exactly one multiplier $5$, and it must have no power of $2$, i.e. $2, 2^2, 2^3,...$ But it may have powers of other primes such as $3^k,7^k,11^k,13^k,...$, $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ but notice that not all them satisfies the condition $n < 50$ when multiplied by $5$ (like $5 
\cdot 11 = 55$ or $5 \cdot 3^3 = 135$, etc.), which $n$ must have as a multiplier. So we can have

- $n = 5$,
- $n = 5\cdot 3 = 15$, $n = 5 \cdot 3^2 = 45$,
- $n = 5 \cdot 7 = 35$

When $n$ or the given numbers gets larger, this algorithm may be hard to use but for small numbers as in this case, this algorithm should work.